# Dragonfly across applications; Same image_uid, same host, different Basename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dragonfly-gem

I am trying to port existing users from an old 3.1 rails application to a new rails 4.0 application.  I assumed that having the same configuration and same image_uid's would be sufficient to port dragonfly images over.  However, Although the base url and image_uids match, different urls are produced.  old app:

```
1.9.3-p194 :002 > u.image_uid
 => "2013/03/07/19/10/42/209/jake.jpg" 
1.9.3-p194 :003 > u.image.url
 => "http://images.example.com/media/BAhbBlsHOgZmSSInMjAxMy8wMy8wNy8xOS8xMC80Mi8yMDkvamFrZV9zLmpwZwY6BkVU"
```

new app:

```
1.9.3-p194 :002 > u.image_uid
 => "2013/03/07/19/10/42/209/jake.jpg" 
1.9.3-p194 :003 > u.image.url
 => "http://images.example.com/media/W1siZiIsIjIwMTMvMDMvMDcvMTkvMTAvNDIvMjA5L2pha2Vfcy5qcGciXV0"
```

Why is the basename different?

Answer (score 0):

Caused by a security difference between dragonfly versions 0.9.12 and 0.9.14.  Change causes urls to be encoded differently.